# Migration from TFS to VSTS - Action Required on dbo.tbl_Content

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

We are planning a migration from an on-premises TFS to VSTS very shortly. Ahead of the migration, I've run the pre-requisite Validation task and obtained a warning that the current TPC database size exceeds the maximum DacPac limit.

A snippet of the database validation is provided below:

```
The full database size is       187411 MB.
The database metadata  size is   28145 MB.
The database blob size is       159266 MB.
The top 10 largest tables are:

===================================================
Table name                               Size in MB
dbo.tbl_Content                          168583
dbo.tbl_BuildInformation2                3233

===================================================
The File owners are:
===================================================
Owner                                    Size in MB
Build+Git                                67410
TeamTest                                 59261
VersionControl                           18637
```

It is obvious from the above that the dbo.tbl_Content table is the main contributor to the excessive database size and from a VSTS operation perspective, Build+Git and TeamTest are the main culprits. My intention is therefore to focus on the above objects for any database clean up to reduce size.

Question is, how can I achieve this in the most effective and best possible way on the above three objects - dbo.tbl_Content, Build+Git and TeamTest?

Comment: _"most effective and best possible way"_ to do what?

Comment: Perform a clean-up of the three named objects - dbo.tbl_Content,  Build+Git and TeamTest.

Comment: https://jessehouwing.net/tfs-clean-up-your-project-collection/

Answer (score 1):

I've written an extensive post on all the ways to clean up TFS prior to import:

- https://jessehouwing.net/tfs-clean-up-your-project-collection/

But remember that there is an alternate path that requires a temporary IaaS server setup in Azure with SQL Server and TFS/Azure DevOps Server installed on it. That path may be simpler and faster than trying to clean up what you have and is equally supported.

---

Extract below:

To prepare your TFS Project Collection for migration, you may want to remove (stale) old data to reduce the database size first.

Most actions are already documented here. Queries that can aid in detecting where your space is allocated are also found in this recent support ticket.

### Delete old workspaces

Deleting workspaces and shelvesets can reduce your migration and upgrade times considerably. either use the `tf` commandline or leverage a tool like the TFS SideKicks to identify and delete these.

### Build results

Not just build results, but often overlooked the actual build records can take up a considerable amount of data. Use `tfsbuild destroy` (XAML) to permanently delete the build records. In the past, I've encountered clients who had 1.8 million "hidden" builds in their database and removing them shaved off quite a considerable amount of data. These records were kept around for the warehouse.

In case you run into very slow execution of tfsbuild, [you may need this patched version it has a few fixes that prevent it from trying to download all the build logs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ooujqx41yold01/TFSBuild_2015_patched.7z?dl=0) for every build in your system just to get to the build ids.

### Old team projects

Of course, destroying old team projects can give back a lot of data. Anything you don't need to send to azure helps. You could also consider splitting the collection and to leave behind the old projects. That will give you the option to detach that collection and store it somewhere, should you ever need that data again.

### Redundant files

Deleted branches are a very common hidden size hog. When deleting things in TFVC, they are not actually deleted, they're just hidden. Finding deleted files and especially old development or feature branches can give you back a lot of data. Use `tf destroy` to get rid of them.

You may also want to look for checked in nuget package folders, those can quickly rack up a lot of space as well.

### Code Lens index

Team Foundation Server 2013 introduced server side indexing of TFVC controlled files to allow Visual Studio access to data on who changed which files when directly in the UI. This server-side index can grow quite quickly depending on the size of your code base and churn.

You can control the index through the `tfsconfig codeindex` command. You can specify up to how long ago you want to index `/indexHistoryPeriod:#months`, delete the index altogether `/destroyCodeIndex` or exclude specific problematic files `/ignoreList:add $/path`.

Code Lens is also referenced to as Code Sense and Code Index internally in the product.

[More can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/codeindex-command?view=vs-2015).

In case deleting the index times out, [you read this post on StackOverflow with additional guidance](https://serverfault.com/questions/958090/tfs-2015-codesense-cleanup/). Be careful, manually running SQL on the TFS collection DB's isn't supported.

### Test Attachments

Ohh yes, especially when you use test attachments, these can grow like crazy, depending on your TFS version either use the built-in test attachment cleanup features or use the Test Attachment Cleaner from the TFS power tools.

### XAML Builds

The build definitions themselves won't take a lot of database space, but the build results may. But those have been covered in a previous section.

In the past, I've had to patch tfbuid.exe to handle (very) large amounts of build records, as it tends to try and fetch all build data locally before proceeding with the delete action. You may need to rely on the TFS Client Object Model to achieve a similar result.

### Git Repositories

You may have data in your git repositories that are no longer accessible due to force pushes or deleted branches. It's also possible that certain data in Git could be packed more efficiently. To clean your repositories you have to clone them locally, clean them up, delete the remote repo from TFS and push the cleaned copy to a new repository (you can use the same name as the old one). Doing this will break references with existing build definitions and you will have to fix these up. While you're at it, you could also run the [BFG repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) and convert the repositories to enable Git-LFS support to handle large binary files in your repositories more elegantly.

```
git clone --mirror https://tfs/project/repo
# optionally run BFG repo cleaner at this point
git reflog expire --expire=now --all 
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git repack -adf
# Delete and recreate the remote repository with the same name
git push origin --all
git push origin --tags
```

### Work item (attachments)

Work items can gather up a considerable amount of data, especially when people start attaching large attachments to them. You can use `witadmin destroywi` to delete work items with unreasonably large attachments. To retain the work item, but delete its attachments you can delete the attachments from the current work item and then clone it. After cloning, destroy the old work item to allow the attachments to be cleaned up.

Old work items that you no longer need (say the sprint items from 6 years ago) can also be deleted. [My colleague René has a nice tool that allows you to bulk-destroy by first creating the appropriate work item query](https://roadtoalm.com/2015/01/14/bulk-destroy-work-items-from-team-foundation-server/).

### Be sure to run the cleanup jobs

TFS often doesn't immediately prune data from the database, in many cases, it just marks stuff as deleted for later processing. To force the cleanup to happen immediately, run the following stored procedures on your Project Collection database:

```
EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent 1
# You may have to run the following command multiple times, the last
# parameter is the batch size, if there are more items to prune than the 
# passed in number, you will have to run it multiple times
EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 100000
```

That 100000 at the end is the number of marked items to process. If you've deleted a lot of content you may need to run that last procedure a couple of times before everything will be deleted.

### Other useful queries

To identify how much data is stored in each section, there are a few useful queries you can run. The actual query depends on your TFS version, but since you're preparing for migration I suspect you're on TFS 2017 or 2018 at the moment.

Find the largest tables:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    o.name, 
    SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024 SizeInMB,
    SUM(
        CASE 
              WHEN p.index_id &lt;= 1 THEN p.row_count
              ELSE 0
        END) Row_Count
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
JOIN sys.objects o
    ON p.object_id = o.object_id
GROUP BY o.name
ORDER BY SUM(reserved_page_count) DESC
```

Find the largest content contributors:

```
SELECT Owner = 
    CASE
        WHEN OwnerId = 0 THEN 'Generic' 
        WHEN OwnerId = 1 THEN 'VersionControl'
        WHEN OwnerId = 2 THEN 'WorkItemTracking'
        WHEN OwnerId = 3 THEN 'TeamBuild'
        WHEN OwnerId = 4 THEN 'TeamTest'
        WHEN OwnerId = 5 THEN 'Servicing'
        WHEN OwnerId = 6 THEN 'UnitTest'
        WHEN OwnerId = 7 THEN 'WebAccess'
        WHEN OwnerId = 8 THEN 'ProcessTemplate'
        WHEN OwnerId = 9 THEN 'StrongBox'
        WHEN OwnerId = 10 THEN 'FileContainer'
        WHEN OwnerId = 11 THEN 'CodeSense'
        WHEN OwnerId = 12 THEN 'Profile'
        WHEN OwnerId = 13 THEN 'Aad'
        WHEN OwnerId = 14 THEN 'Gallery'
        WHEN OwnerId = 15 THEN 'BlobStore'
        WHEN OwnerId = 255 THEN 'PendingDeletion'
    END,
    SUM(CompressedLength) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 AS BlobSizeInMB
FROM tbl_FileReference AS r
JOIN tbl_FileMetadata AS m
    ON r.ResourceId = m.ResourceId
    AND r.PartitionId = m.PartitionId
WHERE r.PartitionId = 1
GROUP BY OwnerId
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

If file containers are the issue:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN Container = 'vstfs:///Buil' THEN 'Build'
        WHEN Container = 'vstfs:///Git/' THEN 'Git'
        WHEN Container = 'vstfs:///Dist' THEN 'DistributedTask'
        ELSE Container 
    END AS FileContainerOwner,
    SUM(fm.CompressedLength) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 AS TotalSizeInMB
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(c.ArtifactUri, 13) AS Container,
    fr.ResourceId,
    ci.PartitionId
FROM tbl_Container c
INNER JOIN tbl_ContainerItem ci
    ON c.ContainerId = ci.ContainerId
    AND c.PartitionId = ci.PartitionId
INNER JOIN tbl_FileReference fr
    ON ci.fileId = fr.fileId
    AND ci.DataspaceId = fr.DataspaceId
    AND ci.PartitionId = fr.PartitionId) c
INNER JOIN tbl_FileMetadata fm
    ON fm.ResourceId = c.ResourceId
    AND fm.PartitionId = c.PartitionId
GROUP BY c.Container
ORDER BY TotalSizeInMB DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Jesse for all your efforts in your site and post, i know i found it in the past as well.
What i am running into right now is that my pipelines://b FileContainer grew to 110GB in size. Do you have a suggestion on how to narrow this down to a project or maybe even the largest build definitions?
Running "TFS" 2019 btw.

Comment: It's been a long time I've had to dig into that part of the schema. There must be an identifier that you can trace back to the project, or, my guess, the Build Definition ID.

Comment: @Nico had a client request to dig a little deeper... the query is still rough, but it aggregates to the Team Project and Repo/Release Definition/Build Definition. Doesn't cover all data types yet and may need some further tweaking in the wild... https://gist.github.com/jessehouwing/97de4849a8a81cf3ebc39a9eab4e8f0d

Comment: Thanks Jesse ! In case you are interested, i ran your script. It ran for 11 minutes and returned 608 rows. The largest row has the project set and the FriendlyName NULL, this row is 47GB and shows to have 487344 rows.
The 2nd row is a build definition claiming 16GB in 4834 rows.
Is the NULL expected or is that something you might be working on ? If you want and of my data let me know if i can help.

Comment: @nico I have implemented a couple of lookups. Without more data (and access to the database) it's hard to say why it's returning null.

Answer (score 0):

My TFS 2015 server was hosting several GIT repositories, some having very large files (with LFS). Using TFS web interface, I deleted some test repos which was taking much storage in tbl_content, I noticed that files were not removed from database.

I tried almost everything. tf delete is useless because repo was already removed.
Stored procedures prc_* did not help very much. Just reduced size from 50 GB to 41 GB

The only way to properly cleanup the tbl_content database is following SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_content WHERE ResourceId IN (SELECT A.[ResourceId]  
  FROM [dbo].[tbl_Content] As A
  WHERE A.ResourceId NOT IN (SELECT X.ResourceId FROM tbl_filemetadata as X)
  AND A.ResourceId NOT IN (SELECT Y.ResourceId from tbl_filereference as Y))
```

This procedure took more than half an hour. After that I performed a database shrink. And now table size is 17 GB.

Now I will move all GIT repositories from TFS to self hosted Gitea server. Very lightweight and efficient server compared to greedy and unmaintenable TFS...